# How to view individual perfomance of Browsers and Network in VSTS 2008 load testing?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, load-testing

In VSTS 2008 load test there is an option to add several browsers and network for load testing. Is there any way to view the performance of these individual browsers and networks in the summary report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible. We create a real world user scenario my adding multiple browser type and different network type. And as per those setting our test agents send request to test servers. But I don't think you can add those individual browsers/networks as a counter in the summary report.

But If you want to see your application performance during real load test, then simple launch it using multiple browsers during load test and check the page load time.

Comment: It is available in VS 2010. There is a new option called "details". select "pages" option in drop down and perform a mouse over on the graph. We can see the browser and network information over there.

Comment: can you please guide me to any documentation, if you have any. Or any screenshot.